# How to iterate an Object and remove all branches filtering by a string

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have an object with this interface:

```
export interface Role {
  children: Role[];
  name: string;
}
```

and I want to filter it by a string, iterate it without knowing how deep it can get, and if a children in, let's say, iteration 4, has in it's name part of that string, keep that child with all it's parents upwards.

Comment: Could you share what you might have tried so far?

Comment: The thing is I don't know how to approach this problem. I thought about creating a function which receives an object and if that object has children it sends them recursively to the same function which returns true if the element has the text, but I don't know how to reproduce that in code.

Comment: A recursive solution is generally the way to go. I'll try to share a solution in a few minutes to help solidify that train of thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a straightforward solution that should account for any number of children or siblings.

Given the input of a role, `filterRole` will return the Role tree/object without child nodes/child node paths that don't pass the filter. Consequently, it shows long/deep paths where innermost children do pass the filter but parents do not.

```
interface Role {
  children: Role[];
  name: string;
}

// Build the Role tree
const invalidChildNode = {name: 'this should be ignored', children: []}
const childNode = {name: 'child', children: []}
const parentNode = {name: 'parent', children: [childNode, invalidChildNode]};
const root = {name: 'root', children: [parentNode]};

/** filterRole takes in a single Role and strips it of all children/paths that do not satisfy the filter at any point. */
const filterRole = (role: Role, filter: string) => {
  let children = role.children;

  if (children.length > 0) {
    children = role.children.map(childRole => filterRole(childRole, filter)).filter(r => r !== null) as Role[];
  }  
  
  // We rebuild this role node with the correct children that recursively passed the filter, either by themselves or within their subtrees.
  return role.name.includes(filter) || children.length > 0 ? {
    ...role,
    children
  }: null;
}

console.log(filterRole(root, 'child')) // this should return the full tree without the "this should be ignored" node.
console.log('-----------');
console.log(filterRole(root, 'ignored')) // this should return the full tree without the "child" node.
console.log('-----------');
console.log(filterRole(root, 'parent')) // this should only return up to the parent node.
```

[Typescript playground to see it in effect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoHsA2KDeAoZZBAC2EwBMoIQAuNLCAbQF0BuA5EOAWwjoGcwUUAHN2AXzx4E6EIOSgAbnEzByAYVIUAcunIoAvMhxdedAORhS-ZP2LoArhWQAjFMBEh0VcuYA0RFqU1HQskjJyYIFk5Lr6yEYmPHzI5iQx-tEUVLTIYdKy8gAOcDlgcYbGpinmJWWZ6dkheY2xehABSipqmjEVzOLsEfJQ6OhRidUWo+MNQTmhddTl7QPsBZHIMGSQUBjYCcgAFKPYdPsdWzvQAkKiAJQJAHzGHNhRrTmHpxAAdJ-UdaEYAwY4AkC-bAgERWZAvAAMj3whEI4O+DH+82ov24cCKR1aF2eV0wuwuBKCFwC21J0Hu91+NN2J2JUGQAEIDEYQE5MI84DYLix2IRxIQOBwqGAHFAQMgfr9qr9QAhMA59Pwjky6cgAD66rLBCFQmHEOHIeHIAD8rxRyF+Dp+fg4qKxIA44joPMwmAkUmGGMw6BEWuuewYJzGYACaSC5npyAA9InkFZgDY7I5nFKZXKrCgYLzU1QUAB3YBWRxRfPIABEaYz9ic5Fc7k83gg5FrnHavw2-EDwaO5gAtGPxxOR-GhoVByHteHsJHxjGPF4fPHHsnU9ZbE3sxBpbKdwWi0IIGWK03q8QULXWt2vPo+wHsJCh6PJ5Pp-256HaYuEDLtGqRLOAm5JimDZ7lmLayJgACe8qHrmyAOEUqboCeyBgVET5-HgQA)